# node js webpack scss not showing up correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, sass

I'm trying to get my scss to show up correctly.  Most of it is working fine, but for some reason the footer isn't showing up correctly.  I'm using node js and webpack, both of which I am relatively new to.  I'm using the modules style-loader, css-loader and sass-loader.  Most of the page's' scss is working but for some reason the footer is not.  This is the relevant code.

footer.scss:

```
$font-stack: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    p{
        font: 50% $font-stack;
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.scss">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/form.scss">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/header.scss">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/footer.scss">


        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                News Article Processing
            </div>
        </header>

        <main>
            <section>
                <div class="holder">
                <form class="form" onsubmit="return handleSubmit(event)">
                    <input id="URL" type="text" name="input" value="" onblur="onBlur()" placeholder="URL" size="48">
                    <input type="submit" id="input" class="button" name="" value="submit" onclick="return handleSubmit(event)" onsubmit="return handleSubmit(event)">
                </form>
                </div>
            <section>

            <section>
                <div class="results">
                    <div class="box">
                        <strong>Results:</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        Polarity: <div id="polarity"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        Subjectivity: <div id="subjectivity"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        Text: <div id="text"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        Polarity Confidence: <div id="polarityConfidence"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        Subjectivity Confidence: <div id="subjectivityConfidence"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>

        <footer>
            <p>Michael Wycklendt      Udacity</p>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: what design you want for footer can be explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not correct because sass is need to be compiled to css in order to run in web browser so you need to config your webpack like this

```
module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

You can find full code [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

And change in your html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
```